# Updating crossed-out items on loading ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I am fairly new to Android programming and trying to set items in a listview upon loading the information from internal storage.

I have two global arrays that I am using: first one is a String array that has the names of the items in the list, and the second is a boolean array that keeps track of which items are crossed out. I am using a TextView in the listview.

```
main_activity.xml:

<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewMyList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

rowlayout.xml:
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:text="@+id/label" />
```

I have created an onClickListener() which successfully updates the state of each list item:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
// Initialize the list (global list values)
String[] values = new String[0]; // array of items for the list
boolean[] checkedVals = new boolean[0]; // keep track of which items are crossed-off
String localFileName = "myListData.csv";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // read the data from file if present
    readListFromFile();        

    // find the ListView
    ListView lst = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMyList);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.label, values);
    lst.setAdapter(adapter);

    // define what happens on click
    lst.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id)
          {
              // read crossed status and set text flags for strikethrough                 
              if (checkedVals[position])
              {                   
                  TextView text1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.label);
                  text1.setPaintFlags(text1.getPaintFlags() & ~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                  text1.setTextColor(0xff000000);
                  checkedVals[position] = false;
              }
              else
              {
                  TextView text1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.label);
                  text1.setPaintFlags(text1.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                  text1.setTextColor(0xff888888);
                  checkedVals[position] = true;
              }
              // save the data in a file
              saveListToFile();
          }
    });

}
```

So this code works fine for crossing out and un-crossing out the items. I don't know how can I cross-out some of the items (determined by the checkedVals boolean array) without clicking or any activity when I load the list.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom Adapter by extending ArrayAdapter and overriding `getView()`.

The `getView()` method loads every row's layout, this is where you should check if the row is in your `checkedVals` array and draw with the appropriate flags.  This [Google Talk](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html) by an Android lead programmer, Romain Guy, provide a wealth of information about best practices on how to do this.